Angular 18 SSR: [vite] Internal server error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'regular')
I'm trying to add SRR to a legacy Angular application that we have just upgraded to Angular 18.
We have successfully ran:
ng add @angular/ssr

When running ng serve we are getting the following error:
3:06:35 PM [vite] Internal server error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'regular')
      at prepareForHydration (node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm2022/platform-server.mjs:16983:26)
      at eval (node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm2022/platform-server.mjs:17036:3)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (.angular/vite-root/transparency-portal/chunk-7PH555RD.mjs:74:24)
      at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:365:28)
      at _ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:111:43)
      at eval (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:1192:40)
      at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:398:33)
      at _ZoneImpl.runTask (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:158:47)
      at drainMicroTaskQueue (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:577:35)

Note: there is a number of places where we reference the document and window objects. We have wrapped them all around isPlatformBrowser(), until we got to this point where no more errors are being reported from the code we control.

im at the same step have you figured anything out?

i have also refactored out alot of window, localstorage and document usage like you explained in reddit. maybe something in config of server app?

@Fiehra  Actually yes. I was at 18.0.0, upgrading to 18.0.2 fixed the issue.

Btw. we had to make so many code changes that we decided that it's not worth it and shelved SSR for now.

ye its alot of code changes here aswell. damn i cant drop it . im on v18.0.0  will also update  thanks! :)

Upgrading to Angular 18.0.2 (was using 18.0.0) fixed the issue.

after upgrading i only had to wrap ngOnDestroy on my app.component.ts with a platformcheck and i got it working. SSR is working now yay!
